# How to scale a GPIO control line to mitigate system impedance

Tags: impedance, gpio, level-shifting, buffer

I'm trying to build a circuit for a GPIO control line.
Each device tapped into the line operates at 1.80v; the line is held at 1.65v HIGH.
The GPIO output pulse profile is 1.000s @ HIGH 1.65v + 40ns @ LOW 0.00v

For the GPIO pin to operate a single device successfully, a pull-up (voltage divider) is used with an impedance of 5k.  In this case, 10k & 10k.
**See illustration**

To scale the system from 1 device to 20, I've designed (with your help) a circuit attached to my MCU.  There is a MAX3370 level shifter parked in front of each device that serves as a "buffer" to preserve the signal on the control line.  **See illustration 2**

Question 1: is it possible to infer the impedance of each device from the first illustration?  Is it 5k per device?  *See update at bottom of post from vendor.

Question 2: Does this design appear to mitigate the voltage drop due to device impedance such that the last device in line will still operate (ignoring degradation due to distance)?

Question 3: Is it a bad idea to split the 3.3v from the source, where one branch serves as Vcc and the other as Vl?  IOW - will this bury the MCU's power source and/or GPIO pin?

I'm a rookie, so thank you in advance for a dumbed down version that I can absorb and any nudge in the right direction.

[image: Illustration 1]

[image: Illustration 2]

[image: MAX3370]

UPDATE:
From the device vendor:

Impedances are not specified precisely.

- When the camera is powered up, and configured as a source, XVS output impedance is low.
- When the camera is powered up, and configured as a sink, XVS input impedance is high.
- When the camera is powered off, XVS will be clamped to the 1.8V supply rail, so there will be significant leakage.

There's an additional 22 Ohm resistor on the board.  Strictly, XVS should not be driven high when the camera is powered off. Using 10K resistors for a pull-up should limit the current to a safe value in all cases, though it might not reliably pull up when there are multiple cameras in parallel and some of them are powered off.

[image]

Comment: What are the specs of the data signal?  Can your MCU drive 20 ICs on the output? Why use autosensing bi-directional level shifter if you don't need bi-directionality and the autosensing part usually causes problems when you use the part in an incorrect environment with long wires, high capacitances, and slow signal slew rates. So can you dig out some more info what devices those are and how 20 of them are wired and connected?

Comment: The signal line is intended to carry a pulse: 1.000s HIGH + 40ns LOW.  Every device on the control line responds to that single signal on its own trigger pin (the devices aren't individually addressed).  The devices are RaspPi HQ cameras; there is a schematic, but the vendor won't release all of the operating specs and they have never been operated "in bulk batch" so there's no precedent for this.  I've invented a wiring diagram that puts them all in parallel, such that they tap into the control line.

Comment: I'm hoping that what I'm asking for, how to design a GPIO operated control line that doesn't succumb to voltage drop, has already been done a zillion times... but I can't seem to find a any examples of it.  Correct - I don't need a bi-directional shifter, but not sure how to select a more correct part yet.  The only device impedance and recommendation that I have from the vendor is at the end of the post above.  If there's something specific needed, LMK what it is, and I'll upload it.  Thx!

Comment: Well, you simply can't take a single  GPIO signal and wire it around in cable to 20 devices on a table or around a room. You need to provide the datasheets of the chips being connected together, to figure out their electrical specifications to come up with a plan to distribute the single signal to all the required places with required timing and delay, within allowable timing distortion etc. It might be best if you revert to "how do I do X" instead of "I will do X with Y, but need help doing Y", but not telling what the original X is. Provide names for the ICs, links to data sheets, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I've uploaded the device schematic above and the vendor impedance notes are above; that's all I have.  The trigger pin on each device is labelled "XVS" on the lower left; it's one of the test pins.  The manufacturer provides a configuration example with 2 devices where the XVS pin can be used bi-directionally (a device configured as MASTER sends a signal, a device configured as SLAVE receives a signal). When 3 devices are connected, it fails.  I can use an either a MASTER or an MCU; in either case, how do I deliver and preserve the signal to 20 of these devices in parallel?  Thx!

Comment: Note to anyone reading this, this is an extension of his question here (where he gives a lot more detail): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/690741/50290  In that question we calculated that each load is about 50kOhm and that he needs a level translator/buffer if he wants to drive them all in parallel.

Comment: Assuming all of the cameras are reasonably close to each other, you can use one level translator for everything since the load impedance is very high.  If they're not, give the distances.  I would use a 1.8V powered device that is 3.3V tolerant (meaning it does not need a 3.3V supply).  You could also use the 1.8V supply on the first camera and avoid the need for the regulator (although it is fine to add one if you want).

Comment: Hi, @user1850479 I appreciate your help.  I'm asking this question generically here, for future GPIO controlled batches of devices.  Devices 1m apart on the control line, and 15cm tap from the control line to the device.  Thanks again!